# Fetching Remote Images Asynchrounously for an ImageAdapter

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, galleryview

I have an Android Gallery ImageAdapter implementation for getView() that looks as follows:

```
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    String strURL = "http://app1.exactdev.co.za/android/celebs/celeb" + (arg0+1) + ".jpg";      
    Bitmap bm = RemoteBitMapHelper.getRemoteBitMap(strURL); //synchronous request               

    ImageView i = new ImageView(ctx);       
    i.setImageBitmap(bm); 
    return i;
}
```

How can I make getView do its job asynchronously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is you could put it inside an AsyncTask. Something like the following (untested)

```
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

    final ImageView i = new ImageView(ctx);
    String url = "http://app1.exactdev.co.za/android/celebs/celeb" + (arg0 + 1) + ".jpg";

    new AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>() {

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            return RemoteBitMapHelper.getRemoteBitMap(urls[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            if (result != null) {
                i.setImageBitmap(result);
            }
        }

    }.execute(url);

    return i;
}
```

Comment: Hasn't really improved my galleries performance like I hoped, but this works like I expected it to, like a charm!.  Quickly implemented a simple public static Map<String, Bitmap> picsMap = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>() to cache images already downloaded and performance is up by like 300%. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm slowly learning exactly how everything groks together with the Android api. This answer has helped a lot.

Comment: getView can be called many times for the same item: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618272/custom-listview-adapter-getview-method-being-called-multiple-times-and-in-no-coh