# Weird Behaviour of ListView with CheckBox

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-manifest

I am having a CheckBox above the ListView having Checkbox items in it. So when I check the Checkbox I apply `notifyDataSetChanged()` to check all the check all the items of the List. So at that time I am getting logs for getView method two times, it means getView is getting called twice when I am calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` only once. So, can anyone tell me why I am getting logs twice? Also why getView() is called twice?

Main Class -

```
checkAll = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.my_check_box);
        checkAll.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton checkbox, boolean arg1) {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Code for Adapter Class -

```
    public class myAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

    private final List<Model> list;
    private final Activity context;
    private CheckBox checkAll;

    public myAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list, CheckBox checkAll) {
        super(context, R.layout.row, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.checkAll = checkAll;

    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView text;
        protected CheckBox checkbox;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
            viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
            viewHolder.checkbox
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                            Model element = (Model) viewHolder.checkbox.getTag();
                            element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                        }
                    });
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        } else {
            view = convertView;
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        }
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());


        if(checkAll.isChecked() == true){
            System.out.println(position+" checked th position");
        }
        else if(checkAll.isChecked() == false){
            System.out.println(position+" not checked th position");
        }

        holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());    
        return view;
    }
}
```

LogCat Output When I can `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` on CheckAll checkboxs Check Change Listener.

```
11-30 20:31:33.751: INFO/System.out(1300): 0 checked th position
11-30 20:31:33.761: INFO/System.out(1300): 1 checked th position
11-30 20:31:33.770: INFO/System.out(1300): 2 checked th position
11-30 20:31:33.780: INFO/System.out(1300): 3 checked th position
11-30 20:31:33.810: INFO/System.out(1300): 4 checked th position
11-30 20:31:33.810: INFO/System.out(1300): 0 checked th position
11-30 20:31:33.831: INFO/System.out(1300): 1 checked th position
11-30 20:31:33.831: INFO/System.out(1300): 2 checked th position
11-30 20:31:33.851: INFO/System.out(1300): 3 checked th position
11-30 20:31:33.860: INFO/System.out(1300): 4 checked th position
```

You can see that I the Logcat output I am getting the same output two times. So can anyone tell the why this is happening?

Comment: this problem also raise with me ... +1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618272/custom-listview-adapter-getview-method-being-called-multiple-times-and-in-no-co check this

Comment: @Lalit Poptani Do you scroll?

Comment: @Venky no I am not scrolling I only have 4 items.

Comment: @LalitPoptani  Hello I am scrolling and multiple select and select all , single select . Single , multiple , select all working fine but when scrolling then position is changes, and all deselect. So how can I solve that issue.

Comment: @Venky Hello I am scrolling and multiple select and select all , single select . Single , multiple , select all working fine but when scrolling then position is changes, and all deselect. So how can I solve that issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try making your `ListView` height `fill_parent`.
Lisiview try itself to adjust a bit as per space provided, this is what I learned, and looks like this is the reason behind.

See if it helps.

Comment: that means when you want to set your listview in half of the screen..you can't resolve the above problem?

Comment: if you want to set your listview in half of the screen, you can use android:layout_weight for that

Answer (score 3):

This is not really an answer to your question - it's just that it hurts my eyes a little when I see this:

```
if(checkAll.isChecked() == true){
    System.out.println(position+" checked th position");
}
else if(checkAll.isChecked() == false){
    System.out.println(position+" not checked th position");
}
```

The `if-statement` requires a `boolean` expression and since the method `isChecked()` returns a `boolean` theres no need to match it up against `true/false`. Also since a `boolean` can only be `true` or `false` there's no need to check for both. In short you can boil the above down to:

```
if( checkAll.isChecked() )
  System.out.println(position+" checked th position");
else
  System.out.println(position+" not checked th position");
```

Which is much prettier :-)

Do not see this as critique of your programming skills - just see it as a learning opportunity.

Comment: Well its just an Demo App for getting the exact idea about my problem. Thanks than too.

Comment: That's hilarious, kaspermoerch! Try this:  
  
`System.out.println(position + (checkAll.isChecked() ? " checked th position" : " not checked th position"));`

Comment: That works too, Jeff. I do find though, that the ternary operator should be used with caution. It doesn't always improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

this is bacause viewHolder inside checkchangelistener will change along with list scrolling . so no mapping betwen i'th checkbox and viewHolder can acheve using this way .

create sepatera class  checkchangelistener implements checnChecnglistener . pass  checkchangelistener through constructor .

**EG. outside getView**

```
class MyCheckChangeLsitenet implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener

ViewHolder viewHolder
 MyCheckChangeLsitenet(ViewHolder viewHolder)
 {
this.viewHolder =  viewHolder ;
}
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                            Model element = (Model) viewHolder.checkbox.getTag();
                            element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                        }
                    });
```

**in GetView**

viewHolder.checkbox
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new MycheckChangeListenet(viewHolder))

Comment: I am not scrolling list currently though its giving the same problem.

Comment: forget the term scroll . trying to make you familiar with internal listView processing . go through described way . it will solve your problem

Comment: you're right @ShailendraSinghRajawat... but the  common model isn't that way, any other simple ways out?