# Android : get List item height of a custom adapter

Tags: java, android, listview

i'm using list view within a scrollview. To avoid the list view not scrollable, i need to het the height of list item and set the listview's height.  How to get the list item height while using custom adapter?

Comment: you dont need to put a scroll view within a list view... listviews are automatically scrollable

Answer (score 0):

Remove the parent scrollview... keep the listview as it is... and change height of listview to  `fill_parent` then automatically as new items are populated in the list you can scroll through it to view ones that go out of the screen ... If by setting to fill_parent the ListView forces other views out of the screen manually set the Height by draging the edges in the graphical layout . Either ways no need to use the ScrollView

thanks to @Lalit for pointing out the hazards of setting a ListView to `wrap_content`

Comment: You should never use ListViews layout_height as wrap_content.

Comment: it works perfectly well and just as i expect it to whenever i set t to wrap_content, if that's a wrong practice what should it be set as (genuine question)... anyways certainly a listview shouldnt be within a scrollview? There's no pint doing that , the listview is scrollable within itself...

Comment: Ok let me clear it by [Proof](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340401/weird-behaviour-of-listview-with-checkbox)

Comment: That still raises doubts can you move this to a chat (I dunno how to do it)

Comment: I am always available in [Casual Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1531/casual-chat)