# My ListView is not smooth when I set Bitmap to ImageView

Tags: android

I use adapter with `ListView` this is implementation of `getView`

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    ItemViewHolder viewHolder;
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(resource,parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ItemViewHolder();
        viewHolder.itemTextName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        viewHolder.itemTextExpDate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_exp_date);
        viewHolder.itemImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);

    }
    else{

        viewHolder = (ItemViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    Item item = listItem.get(position);
    if(listItem != null){
        viewHolder.itemTextName.setText(item.getName());
        viewHolder.itemTextExpDate.setText(""+item.getDaysleft());
        viewHolder.itemImage.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());       
    }
    return convertView;
}

static class  ItemViewHolder  {
    View baseView;
    TextView itemTextName;
    TextView itemTextExpDate;
    ImageView itemImage;


}
```

When I set `Bitmap` to `ImageView` the `ListView` is not smooth.

Am I implement the correct code in `getView` ?

Answer (score 0):

Look on this simple code how you can use [Holder pattern](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/viewholder-pattern-caching-view-efficiently/) simple [implementation](http://www.androidsnippets.com/baseadapter-placeholder-pattern) you must only extern it

On start use Integer.toString or something not

```
viewHolder.itemTextExpDate.setText(""+item.getDaysleft());
```

When you use setImage... the  getView will be called multiple times.

Why you are checking is it null and 1 line faster you use it ? No sense.

```
if(listItem != null){
        viewHolder.itemTextName.setText(item.getName());
        viewHolder.itemTextExpDate.setText(""+item.getDaysleft());
        viewHolder.itemImage.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());       
    }
```

And the most important thing you don't set holder on the View this code doesn't crash for you?

Look at topics:

[Lazy loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)
[getView called multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463387/android-listview-getview-being-called-multiple-times-on-unobservable-views) 
[getView called multiple times 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186004/yet-another-getview-called-multiple-times)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding : `convertView.setTag(viewHolder)` in the if-block. Also, use a method like [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) for loading images in list view