# How does ArrayAdapter.getView() work?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I am extending `ArrayAdapter<UrlItem>` class and have overridden the following method:

```java
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
}
```

I observed that, this method gets called several times. I want to ask, how do you know how many times this gethod gets called to return the View? I want to know how `getView()` works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is absolutely no guarantee on the order in which `getView()` will
>   be called nor how many times.

Look at this SO Question [custom listview adapter getView method being called multiple times, and in no coherent order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618272/custom-listview-adapter-getview-method-being-called-multiple-times-and-in-no-co) and a nice tutorial  http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296 .

Answer (score 1):

No. of getview calling method is depend on no. of objects or size of arraylist you passed in adapter. suppose you want to display 5 items in listview of gridview then this method is called 5 times.

Comment: No, Its not true.. Try with your code, Set adapter to `Listview` and debug your `getView()`code. Also fix the arraylist size. Also try this on different size devices..