# In gridview adapter, getView(position == 0) was invoked too many times to measure layout when setImageBitmap() in a loader

Tags: android, android-view, android-gridview

I have a `GridView` for showing some icons.

BEFORE I had read this [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) from Android developer site, I was decoding bitmap from local path directly in `getView()` of adapter, like this :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      ...
      ImageView icon = ...... (from getTag() of convertView)
      icon.setImageBitmap(BitmapUtil.decode(iconPath));
      ...
}
```

this way works fine anyway, I called it [Direct Mode], the output log for `getView()` method should be :

```
getView(0)   // measure kid's layout.
getView(0)
getView(1)
getView(2)
...
getView(n)       // when scrolling gridview.
getView(n+1)
...
getView(n+3)    // scrolling again.
getView(n+4)
...
```

then I am trying to change the code to [Loader Mode] mentioned in article [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html), as following :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      ...
      ImageView icon = ...... (from getTag() of convertView)
      loadIcon(icon, iconPath);
      ...
}
```

in `loadIcon()` :

```
...
final CacheImageLoader loader = new CacheImageLoader(getActivity(), imageView, imageUrl, savePath);
final AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable = new AsyncDrawable(getResources(), placeHolderBitmap, loader);
imageView.setImageDrawable(asyncDrawable);
```

in Loader's listener :

```
@Override
public void onLoadComplete(Loader<Bitmap> arg0, Bitmap arg1) {
    ...
    ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
    if (result != null && imageView != null) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Basically, it is same as the training code, actually, this way works fine as well. However, I found something different, in this mode the `getView()` method in adapter was invoked too many times, however, these repeat call to this method always with "position" parameter == 0, it means something invoke g`etView(0, X, X)` repeatedly.

```
getView(0)     // measure kid's layout.
getView(0)
getView(1)
getView(2)
...    
getView(0)     // loader completed then imageView.setImageBitmap(result); 
getView(0)     // same as above
getView(0)
getView(0)
...
getView(n)     // when scrolling gridview.
getView(n+1)
getView(n+2)
getView(0)     // loader completed then imageView.setImageBitmap(result); 
getView(0)     // same as above
getView(0)
...
getView(n+3)   // scrolling again.
getView(n+4)
getView(0)     // loader completed then imageView.setImageBitmap(result); 
getView(0)     // same as above
getView(0)
```

It is not good because I am using a loader in `getView()`. I have checked the source code and found they are originally called by **`imageView.setImageBitmap(result)`** in loader's  `onLoadComplete` method, and in `ImageView` :

```
 /**
 * Sets a drawable as the content of this ImageView.
 * 
 * @param drawable The drawable to set
 */
public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        ...

        int oldWidth = mDrawableWidth;
        int oldHeight = mDrawableHeight;

        updateDrawable(drawable);

        if (oldWidth != mDrawableWidth || oldHeight != mDrawableHeight) {
            requestLayout();
        }
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

here, **`requestLayout()`** is View's method and always executes in either [Direct Mode] or [Loader Mode],  in View.class :

```
public void requestLayout() {
    mPrivateFlags |= FORCE_LAYOUT;
    mPrivateFlags |= INVALIDATED;

    if (mLayoutParams != null) {
        mLayoutParams.onResolveLayoutDirection(getResolvedLayoutDirection());
    }

    if (mParent != null && !mParent.isLayoutRequested()) {
        mParent.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

however the difference is: in  [Direct Mode], the  `mParent.requestLayout()` is invoked once, but in [Loader Mode], every time when i call **`imageView.setImageBitmap(result);`**, the  `mParent.requestLayout()` will be invoked as well, it means `mParent.isLayoutRequested()` return `false`, and `mParent.requestLayout();` will cause the `GridView` measure its kid's layout by calling `obtainView()` to first kid and then cause `getView(0, X, X)` :

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    ...
    mItemCount = mAdapter == null ? 0 : mAdapter.getCount();
    final int count = mItemCount;
    if (count > 0) {
        final View child = obtainView(0, mIsScrap);
    ...
```

---

So, my **question** is: why `mParent.isLayoutRequested()` return `false` if I am using [loader mode]? or is it just a normal case ?

Comment: As far as I know it is normal, Android can call any method of your adapter at any time and as many time as it likes. It even varies from version to version. Never assume anything about it. `GridView` is similar to `ListView` so check out this great talk http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70. Unless you are getting some crash or memory low error, don't worry about it and let it call your methods. And yes in [loader mode] android will refresh GUI later whenever onLoadFinish() is called.

Comment: Check "Settings>Developer Options>Show Layout Updates" and launch your app. If GUI is settled when your all loaders are finished then you are good to go.

Comment: Did you find a way around this? I get this too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [custom listview adapter getView method being called multiple times, and in no coherent order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618272/custom-listview-adapter-getview-method-being-called-multiple-times-and-in-no-co)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`isLayoutRequested` is just there to tell you if a layout is already pending for this `View`. That is, after `requestLayout` is called, `isLayoutRequested` will return true until the next layout pass completes. The only reason for this check in `requestLayout` is to avoid repeatedly calling `requestLayout` on the parent if it's about to do layout anyway. `isLayoutRequested` is a red herring here: it's not the cause of `onMeasure` being called repeatedly.

The root problem is that `ImageView` requests a new layout whenever you change its drawable. This is necessary for two reasons:-

1. The size of the ImageView might depend on that of the drawable, if `adjustViewBounds` is set. This might in turn affect the sizes of other views, depending on the layout: the `ImageView` doesn't itself have enough information to know.
2. `ImageView.onMeasure` is responsible for working out how much the drawable has to be resized to fit in the `ImageView`'s  bounds, according to the scale mode. If the new drawable isn't the same size as the old drawable, the `ImageView` **must** be measured again to recompute the required scaling.

You can only fix the problem of having too many loaders by keeping a local cache of `Bitmap`s returned by the loaders. The cache might have all the `Bitmap`s if you know there aren't that many, or just the *n* most recently used ones. In your `getView`, first check if the `Bitmap` for that item exists in the cache, and if so, return an `ImageView` already set to that `Bitmap`. Only if it's not in the cache do you need to use a loader.

Be careful: if the underlying data can change, you now need to make sure to invalidate the cache at the same time as calling `invalidate` on the `GridView` or notifying through `ContentResolver`. I've used some homebrew code to achieve this in my app, and it works nicely for me, but the good folks at Square have an open-source library called [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to do all the hard work for you if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavioral, android can call getView for same position multiple time. It's on developer to get/set thumbnail in getView only when required (i.e. If thumbnail was not set Or thumbnail path has changes). In other cases just return convertView, which we get as parameter in getView.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Grid is always measuring its first child, even if I am in 30 position. 
I just bypass the whole getView code by adding this check in getView top:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Patch for multiple getView for position 0
    if(convertView!=null && position==0 && viewGrid.getFirstVisiblePosition()>1) return convertView;
```

This does not stop getView being called, but at least texts, images and layout changes don' t run.

Comment: If you can have more than one item per row, change the "1" with the max number of items per row.

Answer (score 0):

try adjust your xml layout on anyone place that references the height, because the android will do a measure to draw eachtime and will redraw the cell up again.
Try use on listview match_parent and on cell at row an exactly height.
sorry my bad english.