# Android listview keep showing the same rows

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

It's seems that i have the same problem as this question : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618272/custom-listview-adapter-getview-method-being-called-multiple-times-and-in-no-co).
But my listview already have fill_parent for height. I did a debug, and it stops after 4 rows and it keeps looping the same ones.

Here's my code :

```
public class NewsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
List<News> news;
private Context context;
public NewsAdapter(Context context, List<News> news) {
    this.context = context;
    this.news = news;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return news.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return news.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if(v == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_news, null);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tv_title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_adapter_news_title);
        holder.tv_description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_adapter_news_description);
        holder.tv_date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_adapter_news_date);
        //
        holder.siv_picture = (SmartImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.siv_adapter_news_picture);
        //
        holder.view_color = (View) v.findViewById(R.id.v_adapter_news_color);
        ///
        String type = news.get(position).getNewsType();
        String title = news.get(position).getNewsTitle();
        String description = news.get(position).getNewsDescription();
        String picture = news.get(position).getNewsPicture();
        String date = news.get(position).getNewsDate();
        String link = news.get(position).getNewsLink();
        String id = news.get(position).getNewsId();

        if(title != null){
            holder.tv_title.setText(title);
        }
        if(description != null){
            holder.tv_description.setText(description);
        }
        if(picture != null){
            holder.siv_picture.setImageUrl(picture);
        }else{
            holder.siv_picture.setImageUrl("http://aovivo.slbenfica.pt/Portals/3/noticias/Epoca2012_13/Futebol%20Profissional/CampeonatoNacional_2012_13/Benfica_fcPorto/SLB_Futebol_Matic_Festejos_Benfica_FCPorto_13Janeiro2013_V.jpg?w=227");
        }
        if(date != null){
            holder.tv_date.setText(date);
        }
        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase(News.CATEGORY_ARTICLE)){
            holder.view_color.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            if(date != null){
                holder.tv_date.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }

        }else{
            holder.view_color.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView);
    return v;
}
static class ViewHolder {
    public SmartImageView siv_picture;
    public TextView tv_title;
    public TextView tv_description;
    public TextView tv_date;
    public View view_color;
}

}
```

And here's the xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="100" 

>

<!-- Photo part -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dim20dp" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dim20dp" 
    >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/v_adapter_news_color"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <com.loopj.android.image.SmartImageView
        android:id="@+id/siv_adapter_news_picture"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" 
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        />
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Text Part -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="70"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dim20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dim20dp"
    >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv_adapter_news_date"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="date"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dim5dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_adapter_news_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title" 
        style="@style/news_text_title"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dim15dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_adapter_news_description"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/news_text_description"
        android:text="description" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in the `getView` where you check to see if `v == null` which is good but what happens if v is NOT null... you dont handle that so its reusing the last view which is why you are seeing multiples

you should be doing this

```
if(v == null){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_news, null);
}

//then set the views after you do the check so it is always done
```

Comment: I'm on it since this morning, thank you, i didn't even noticed.

Answer (score 1):

You getView() implementation does not handle the case where convertView is not null. Make sure you are using setTag() and getTag() to bind the ViewHolder to that view.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    View v = convertView;
    if(v == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_news, null);

        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tv_title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_adapter_news_title);
        // etc...

        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = v.getTag();
    }

    News item = getItem(position);
    holder.tv_title.setText(item.getNewsTitle());
    // etc...

    return v;
}
```

Comment: i know what the ViewHolder is for but what is the use of tag, because i didn't set the tag and it worked anyway ?

Comment: The tag is the whole reason `ViewHolder` works. You do this so that when a view is recycled you do not need to call `findViewById()` to get all the child views again -- they're already referenced byt the ViewHolder, so you just call `getTag()` and cast it to a `ViewHolder`.