# How can I append to file in a listview?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-listview, android-adapter

I am trying to write data to a file each time getView() is called in a adapter. I append to the file every time the call is made with a string value (the row data of the listview).

I do not open the file every single time because the performance is affected severely if I do so. Hence, I keep the stream open and only append and write new line every time getView() is called.

When I open the file later after my operations are complete, I see each row duplicated in my file at least 5-6 times! The file is much larger than it should be. I see the correct values on my ListView though.

I perform appends in a new thread within the getView() method (I do not use a AsyncTask. I just say new Thread() { run() {//My operation}}.start().

I am using Android 4.0. I think the issue with getView() getting called more than once for every row has been fixed. Or has it?

Any ideas??

Comment: Maybe if you paste that portion of your code it will be clearer as to how to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Romain Guy's response in [custom listview adapter getView method being called multiple times, and in no coherent order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618272/custom-listview-adapter-getview-method-being-called-multiple-times-and-in-no-co). To quote him `"This is not an issue, there is absolutely no guarantee on the order in which getView() will be called nor how many times."`

It may also be possible that your ListView has a `layout_width` set to `wrap_content`. Again, see the above link for more info.