# getCount() of baseAdapter called many times

Tags: android

i have this class which extends `BaseAdapter` that i use to insert an icon and a `textView` for each row of a listView that is inside a drawer

```
public class NavRightDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
LinkedList<String> userNameUsedForListView;
Map<String, Bitmap> urlUserImage;

public NavRightDrawerListAdapter(Context context, LinkedList<String> userNameUsedForListView, Map<String, Bitmap> returnBitMapFromURL) {
    this.context = context;
    this.userNameUsedForListView = userNameUsedForListView;
    this.urlUserImage = returnBitMapFromURL;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int count = 0;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_of_action, null);
    }

    ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

    imgIcon.setImageBitmap(urlUserImage.get(userNameUsedForListView.get(count)));
    txtTitle.setText(userNameUsedForListView.get(count));
    count++;
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return userNameUsedForListView.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

my list size is 1, and getView is called 1 time,normally, but getCount is called six times?
why? is a normal behaviour?

*i didn't implement the method,`getItem()` and `getItemId()`,because i don't need them, i have to implement them anyway?*

thanks a lot.

Comment: Adapter methods may be called an arbitrary number of times while the AdapterView is readying and laying out its child Views. So, yes, it's normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapter methods may be called an arbitrary number of times while the AdapterView is readying and laying out its child Views. So, yes, it's normal.

I'm unable to find a source that explicitly states that this is the case for `getCount()`, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618272/custom-listview-adapter-getview-method-being-called-multiple-times-and-in-no-co/2639159#2639159) by [Romain Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298575/romain-guy) notes how there is no guarantee how many times `getView()` will be called. One can see how that method would interplay with `getCount()`, which would, therefore, also need to be called an uncertain number of times.