# Android - delayed setImage on list item causes the onMeasure to be invoked and hence to repaint everything from position 0

Tags: android, listview, imageview, listadapter, onmeasure

I have a listview showing rows containing images from the web.

once a row needs to be drawn, in `Adapter.getView(...)`, I download the image in the background and set it to the `ImageView` in the UI thread. This means that the bitmap is being set into the ImageView in a delayed manner.

I tried the delayed setImage...() with simple drawable resources and the result was the same.

**I observed that setting a resource in a delayed mannger, causes the whole list to be redrawn starting with position 0, which is not even shown - up to the shown position.** The obvious problem is that the list scroll is slow and jumpy and not smooth.

I want to be extra careful here: This happens while scrolling a bit. The new seen items do get drawn as part of the regular `makeAndAddView`. But, immediately after that all the rows leading up to the seen rows are being painted as part of `measureHeightOfChildren`.

Setting the image immediately and not delayed does not cause the `onMeasure` to be invoked.

**So how do I prevent the repaint of all the list and why is the behavior different between the immediate setImage and the delayed?**

Comment: Oh, and I tested it on several Android device versions: 4.1.2, 4.3 and 4.4.4.

Comment: Oh, look what I found. I found a todo in Android's code to measure, starting from the first visible position and not 0. Quote: `// TODO: after first layout we should maybe start at the first visible position, not 0`. See for yourself: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/widget/ListView.java#ListView.onMeasure%28int%2Cint%29

Comment: Anyhow, a question still remains: why is the measurement requested in the immediate `setImage` scenario and not the delayed scenario?

Comment: I wrote some logic in the adapter to ignore unseen positions but the rendering is still very slow.

Comment: The following answer prevent the repainting of everything: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2639159/435605

Answer (score 0):

The delayed vs. un-delayed `setImage...()` question still remains unsolved.

I did manage to prevent the measurement on the delayed scenario by setting the listview's `layout_height` to `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content`.