# How to have a button below a listview which has match_parent as width and height in android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I am working on a project which has a custom listview.Since the `getView()` method of the baseadapter kept being called thrice the number of rows in the listview,someone suggested that i change the width and height of the listview to `match_parent`.But now the problem is that there is a button below the listview,which is not visible now.How do i make it visible.

The post i was referring to:[custom listview adapter getView method being called multiple times, and in no coherent order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618272/custom-listview-adapter-getview-method-being-called-multiple-times-and-in-no-co)

my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="LIST OF TASKS" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_tasks_final"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50px"
     >

</ListView>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/list_tasks_final"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="SUBMIT JOB"
    android:id="@+id/btnjobsubmit"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The issue is that the button is not visible now.How to make it visible?

Comment: Can you brief little bit more? What's your expected result and current result? Would be easy for us to help you if you post this result diagrammatically.

Comment: @YuvaRaj.I want a button below the listview.But since the listview has match_parent , it fills up the entire screen and the button is not visible.I want the button to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

see my code
you should wrap your list view in another view `LinearLayout` for example and set height to that layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LIST OF TASKS" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_tasks_final"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="50px"
            >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="SUBMIT JOB"
        android:id="@+id/btnjobsubmit"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The closing tag for listview should be before linearlayout

Comment: But still i dont see the button in the graphical layout.

Comment: see my new edit! I just added orientation to linear layout and reduced list view's parent's height and now I can see the button!

Comment: @AchuthanM Click `Preview all` and you can see the button in big screen size. Run it in emulator and check whether its working or not.

Comment: @AchuthanM do you still have problem?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `RelativeLayout`, you should use `LinearLayout`. It provides more flexibility in placing different views according to our need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="LIST OF TASKS" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_tasks_final"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout> 

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="SUBMIT JOB"
    android:id="@+id/btnjobsubmit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your list is using all the space of the screen (Layout_height=match_parent, layout_width=match_parent) and the button has the attribute layout_below, then it is shown below the entire screen.

To solve this, just remove the attribute layout_below:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/list_tasks_final"
```

Comment: I want the listview to have match parent for width and height.So obviously it will have fill parent property .So how will the button be visible if the listview occupies the entire screen.?