# Android: convertView parameter in getView() is not null when it should be null

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView with a custom ArrayAdapter, and according to documentation and what I read everywhere, getView() gets called when creating new view (In this case list item) or recycling an old view (convertView),or at least this is what I understood.

Anyway, on my mobile (Note 3 Kitkat), I have a listView that preview at most in the loading mode (The log is below) 3 list items (Visually 2.2 items), of course I can scroll up / down to show full 2 items + 0.2 from the other 2 items (Which means my listView at most will preview 4 list items).

When I set to have a log, getView() is being called 6 times, first time convertView is NULL and followed by 3 times is "NOT null", followed by 2 times "Is Null".

```
01-21 20:11:22.758  11517-11517/www.test.ar D//*/*/ convertView﹕ IS Null - Position is: 0
01-21 20:11:22.903  11517-11517/www.test.ar D//*/*/ convertView﹕ Not Null - Position is: 1
01-21 20:11:22.913  11517-11517/www.test.ar D//*/*/ convertView﹕ Not Null - Position is: 2
01-21 20:11:22.943  11517-11517/www.test.ar D//*/*/ convertView﹕ Not Null - Position is: 0
01-21 20:11:22.963  11517-11517/www.test.ar D//*/*/ convertView﹕ IS Null - Position is: 1
01-21 20:11:23.028  11517-11517/www.test.ar D//*/*/ convertView﹕ IS Null - Position is: 2
```

**So, shouldn't convertView be NULL as long as there is no scrolling down / up, in other words as long as there are no view going out of screen scope?!**

In such case as mine, how many items the ArrayAdapter should create at first loading, 3 items or 4 items?

**The code I use:**

```
public class MyListArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    public MyListArrayAdapter (Context context, String[] aTitles,  String[] aImagesURL)
{
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, aTitles);
}

   @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
       if(convertView == null)
        {
            Log.d("/*/*/ convertView", "IS Null - Position is: " + position);

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("/*/*/ convertView", "Not Null - Position is: " + position);
        }
    }
}
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_with_shadow">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

    <!-- title -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:maxLength="50"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Default Text"/>


    <!-- icon -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:src="@drawable/default_pic"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**background_with_shadow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#DCDCDC" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:right="0.5dp" android:left="0.5dp" android:top="0.0dp" android:bottom="1.0dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">

            <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
            <padding android:left="7dp" android:right="7dp" android:top="7dp" android:bottom="7dp" />
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: Where is this code you speak of?

Comment: @JaredBurrows Please recheck the question, I added the code, thank you.

Comment: Add your list_item.xml

Comment: Check (log) the `position` parameter along with the `convertView` to provide better context of what is happening.  It could be that the `ListView` is pre-caching views then refreshing them as it is being laid out, etc.

Comment: @user3249477 Done, added the list_item.xml file

Comment: @LarrySchiefer Done, please recheck the modified log in my question.

Comment: @user3249477 is spot on in the answer.  The log verifies this: the `ListView` is pulling `View` objects for items in the list as it figures out how to lay them out.

Comment: @LarrySchiefer OK, somehow it makes since, First item must be null so the user inflate it under "if(convertView == null)" and the followed 2 items are being sent as "!=null" to avoid inflating them and the adapter already has the layout measures from the first item .... Then it resend the convertView as != null for the first item (to avoid inflating it again), and null for the other 2 so I inflate them in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time your `ListView` is shown, it will call `getView` multiple times to fetch and measure views that fit on the screen.

You should only be worried if you keep seeing `convertView: IS Null` while scrolling the list.

A similar question has been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2639159/3249477) quite a while ago by one of Google employees. I also strongly suggest watching a [video about ListView performance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70).

Comment: Thank you, but if I want to set the tag of the convertView to hold the position (I'm going to use AsyncTask to download images and set them to the related list item), do I do it in (==null) or in (!=null)? .... I'm setting the covertView tag with position so I can compare the position hold by the AsyncTask object against the current position of the related view.

Comment: @Astrount it should be called in `getView`. Inside of (==null) you inflate and set tag. Inside of (!=null) you get tag and elements. Outside of (and after) everything you do your every-item-work, e.g. fetch and set images.

Comment: Again thank you :) I modified my ListView layout_height to be "fill_parent" rather than "match_parent" (according to the first link you provided) and the repetition of calling getView as in my question is vanished, now it's being called with convertView as I expect [null, null, null] and only for 3 times.