# How do I know when "getView()" is done on ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, custom-adapter, getview

I have a GridView using CustomAdapter, and I have an array list (size=20).

When I call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
 - `getView()` is being called more times than it should (I understand that there is nothing to do about that). But I have a variable `done==false` on CustomAdapter class, and I want to change it to true once `getView()` is done working (after 20 times or even 50 times) , 
How can I control what comes once `getView()` is done?
I want to change this variable to true. Where should I place `done=true`?

*The last `getView()`call is not necessary `position==19`

Comment: Adnroid Documentation says:

When the View is inflated, the parent View (GridView, ListView...) will apply default layout parameters unless you use inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) to specify a root view and to prevent attachment to the root.

Comment: It also likely that requestLayout is being called repeatedly on your GridView as it fills in your grid,  check for an optimizations you can do on your layout views to avoid these extra measuring and layout passes.

Comment: why do you need this `done` flag?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do that!
As Listview refreshes it's childs on scrolling

> There is absolutely no guarantee on the order in which getView() will
>   be called nor how many times.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2639159/5993410)

Comment: But it's not what I asked- I already know that there is no guarantee on the order, I already know that there is no guarantee on the number of calls. But- at the end this method is done right? it's still Java. So what happens once it's done.

Comment: I don't understands what you trying to do, if you put `done == true;` at end of the method it will be true at this call of the method and if done is an field in the adapter then it will remain true.

Comment: I'll change it to false later it's not the issue.  I need to change it to true only once the last call of "getView()" is called (after ** numbers of times)

Comment: you can never detect last call of the method!!, you can only detect bottom of listview [user has scrolled to last row] or top of listview

Comment: I have no scrolling on my app

Comment: same exact issue here