# listview getView() getting wrong position

Tags: android, listview

When I scroll down the listview,it shown wrong item position.
The original listview item position was correct in the screen
but when I scroll down the listview it was getting wrong 
and then I scroll up the listview  all item position will be change not original
position.my question is how to make getVeiw() position to correct sequence when I scroll the listview.

here is my code:

MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

```
private ImageButton btnExit;
private ListView listView;

ArrayList<String>list_name = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String>list_time = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String>list_message = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String>list_image = new ArrayList<>();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnExit = findViewById(R.id.btnExit);
    btnExit.setOnClickListener(btnExitListener);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++) {
        list_name.add("User" + i);
        list_time.add("2018-2-14");
        list_message.add("hello!!");
        list_image.add("http://a1.att.hudong.com/86/38/300001140423130278388082725_950.jpg");
    }
    ListAdapter adapter = new com.ncut.user.cloudtest.ListAdapter(MainActivity.this,list_name,list_time,list_message,list_image);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter); 

}
```

}

ListAdpter.java

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;
ArrayList<String>list_name = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String>list_time = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String>list_message = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String>list_image = new ArrayList<>();


static class ViewHolder{
    TextView name_text;
    TextView time_text;
    TextView message_text;
    ImageView image;

}

public ListAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String>list_name, ArrayList<String>list_time,ArrayList<String>list_message
                    ,ArrayList<String>list_image) {
    super(context, R.layout.listview_chat_room_me, list_name);

    this.context = context;
    this.list_name = list_name;
    this.list_time = list_time;
    this.list_message = list_message;
    this.list_image = list_image;

}
public View getView(int position , View view, ViewGroup parent ){

    Log.d(TAG, "position=" + position);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    if(view == null){

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_chat_room_me,parent,false);

        holder.name_text = view.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        holder.time_text = view.findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
        holder.message_text = view.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
        holder.image = view.findViewById(R.id.imgPersonalPhoto);

    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    try {
        holder.name_text.setText(list_name.get(position));
        holder.time_text.setText(list_time.get(position));
        holder.message_text.setText(list_message.get(position));
        Glide.with(context).load(list_image.get(position)).into(holder.image);
    }
    catch (Exception e){

    }
    return view;
}
}
```

Logcat:

```
05-24 01:05:29.687 21886-21886/com.ncut.user.cloudtest D/ContentValues: position=0
05-24 01:05:29.688 21886-21886/com.ncut.user.cloudtest D/ContentValues: position=1
05-24 01:05:29.689 21886-21886/com.ncut.user.cloudtest D/ContentValues: position=2
05-24 01:05:29.690 21886-21886/com.ncut.user.cloudtest D/ContentValues: position=3
05-24 01:05:29.691 21886-21886/com.ncut.user.cloudtest D/ContentValues: position=4
05-24 01:05:29.692 21886-21886/com.ncut.user.cloudtest D/ContentValues: position=5
05-24 01:05:29.696 21886-21886/com.ncut.user.cloudtest D/ContentValues: position=6
05-24 01:05:29.697 21886-21886/com.ncut.user.cloudtest D/ContentValues: position=7
05-24 01:05:29.698 21886-21886/com.ncut.user.cloudtest D/ContentValues: position=8
05-24 01:05:31.608 21886-21886/com.ncut.user.cloudtest D/ContentValues: position=8
05-24 01:05:36.790 21886-21886/com.ncut.user.cloudtest D/ContentValues: position=0
```

Comment: Don't understand your problem

Comment: My problem is getview position is wrong not Sequential display

Comment: Please have a read through [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618272), then [edit] your question to explain exactly what the problem is, as you should not expect `getView()` to be called in an exact, sequential order.

Comment: ok I will I type more detail to my post